# Create Anaconda environment from existing packages

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to create another environment from a `.yml` file with a pre-existing packages at `Anaconda3/pkgs/*tar.bz2`, but Anaconda keeps downloading the same package which cause overwriting the existing one, and this is a massive problem for a +150 listed packages with a far server from my location (20KB/s)..

So, how can I force it to look at a certain directory(e.g. `Anaconda3/pkgs/`) at first, and if not found, then go to the internet and search for it by the provided repository?